# volttron agent install time out

Tags: agent, volttron

I'm having problem with following Volttron Agent Creation Walkthrough and don't seem to find an answer for it here or elsewhere - sorry if this is too basic.

I'm following the procedure here http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/master/devguides/agent_development/Agent-Development.html#agent-development but when I run:

`volttron-ctl install ~/.volttron/packaged/testeragent-0.1-py2-none-any.whl --tag testagent`

I get the following message: `install: operation timed out`

I've reinstalled volttron and it didn't work either. I'm running it in a vm with Linux mint.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This can occur if you don't have volttron running.  Please verify tnhat there is a volttron process with the command `ps aux|grep volttron`

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for the reply. It looks like I have volttron running. Here is the output of this command:

USER 2291  0.0  0.0  11748  2212 pts/2    S+   19:52   0:00 grep --colour=auto volttron

Comment: I figured out what was going on - and you were right Craig. For some reason the volttron process was getting killed. Now it's working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great let us know if you have any more issues

Answer (score 1):

I have also had the same problem, first of all, you should run:

```
source env/bin/activate
volttron -vv -l volttron.log&
```

(activate and start platform)